# store checkbox value in database on click

Tags: php, mysql

There are several questions on storing whether a check box is checked or not in a database. However my problem is slightly different.

I have several checkboxes **not in a form** and I want to save whether the checkbox is checked or not on click. Means as soon as the user checks the checkbox the value is saved in the mysql database. Is that possible with php?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use Ajax with an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can send checkbox value to server side using below code.

```
// Below code is executed when user check or uncheck the checkbox 
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var booiIsChecked = 0;
   // Below code is executed when user checks the checkbox
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var booiIsChecked = 1;
    }
   // Get checkbox value
    var strCheckboxValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Here Your Server Url"
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "checkbox_value": strCheckboxValue,
            // At server Side you can check if checkbox checked or unchecked.
            "is_checked": booiIsChecked
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I feel that you should elaborate on your answer, since the OP may not know what to do with this and which library should be loaded in order to make this work. If the OP comes back and says *"Hey thanks, that's great!"*, then just disregard my comment.

Comment: @Ali i am using php and i am not so flexible with ajax is this possible in php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you help how i can do so with php - 1.check if the checkbox is checked or not then send it to mysql database

Comment: Have you got the solution ?